# How do I prevent multiple instances of Process.start?

Tags: winforms, process, system.diagnostics

I have a button on my WinForm. Code works great until I observed my test users.

They don't wait for the PDF to launch. Instead they will click it several times (causing multiple instances of the Acrobat reader to launch

```
    private void pictureBoxNewsLetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lockControls();            
        launchNewsLetter();
        unlockControls();
    }
    private void launchNewsLetter()
    {
        // Newsletter
        lockControls();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"Y:\Newsletter.pdf");
        Process ps = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
        ps.Start();
        ps.WaitForExit();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        unlockControls();
    }
```

--- Code to disable my controls.

```
    private void lockControls()
    {
        dontRunHandler = false;
        foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
            pb.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void unlockControls()
    {
        dontRunHandler = true;
        foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
            pb.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might get somewhere with Process.WaitForInputIdle().  Or just plain assume that Acrobat sucks and that clicking the button twice in a row with less than 10 seconds between clicks is not useful.  So disable the button and re-enable it with a timer.

Comment: Thats the route I started to take while waiting for a better answer. In anycase, post it as an answer and I'll award you the question if no one else responds

Comment: I just finished implementing your suggestion. The events are being queued and firing even after disabling the control. Its weird. I'm updating the code above